# Graphic in certain email only displays after clicking away, then back into email (Outlook 2013)

Tags: email, images, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2007

We have a custom email that we send out to our users when their AD passwords are expiring. These are run daily via a Scheduled Task on the email (Exchange 2007 - I know it's old, don't get me started) server and they work very well, run like clockwork. It's just simple HTML + PowerShell for the backend work to audit AD and send the email.

One minor annoyance is that the only-and-only graphic in the email (a .PNG file) does not load on first-click in the email:
[image]

However, when you click away then back into the email the image *does* load. What causes this behavior and how can we correct it so that the image loads on the first time?

Comment: Does this issue only affect the particular message? What if manually sending out the mail to see if the issue persists? You may try going to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Automatic Download, clear the checkbox of "Don't download pictures..." and see the result.

Comment: Thanks, Yuki. It does only affect this particular email, yes. All others are fine.